# Colocar o campo de CPF no checkout, no Magento 2

Tags: magento, e-commerce, checkout

Alguém sabe como colocar o campo de CPF no checkout do Magento2? Existem várias dicas por ai de como colocar em versões anteriores do Magento, mas não encontrei em lugar nenhum como fazer isso na versão nova (Atualmente estou na 2.2.3).

Consegui colocar o campo usando o LayoutProcessor, dessa forma:

```
    $shippingFields['taxvat'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'label' => __('CPF'),
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
        ],
        'placeholder' => 'CPF *',
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => 1
        ],
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'source' => 'customer.taxvat',
        'dataScope' => 'customer.taxvat',
        'sortOrder' => 1,
    ];
```

Mas ele não está salvando no banco de dados.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Obrigado!

Comment: já conseguiu colocar o CPF no checkout?

Comment: Consegui. Usei o VAT como campo. E no plugin de pagamento, peguei o taxvat ou o campo VAT, Dependendo de qual o usuário preencheu (taxvat se fez login, VAT se usou o guest checkout). Usei o plugin do moip para magento2 como referência.